# CakePHP DebugKit error

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-debug-kit

I get this error in my CakePHP 3 app

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cake\Database\Query::toArray() in /home/rrd/public_html/sanga/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Panel/VariablesPanel.php on line 77

Cake 3.1.8
DebugKit 3.2.4

Any idea what is this?

Update: It seems the error comes up when I have some sql error.

Comment: Same error, i get this with `$this->paginate($query)` but not with `$query->all()` or `$query->toArray()`

Comment: @DarioLap it should be an sql error